# Meteor App Can't Run on iOS Device (Mobile Configuration Issue)

Tags: ios, iphone, meteor

I'm having trouble with my iOS build. Not sure what it is.

After running `meteor run ios-device` command. It launches Xcode, but the "build and run" button is greyed out.

[image]

And when i expand the device drop-down, my phone is listed as "ineligible device" and the simulators is not even shown there.

[image]

I suspect there's something wrong inside my [mobile-config.js](https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/389664275b8c6d991999) file. Because when i remove this file, it runs as expected (but with default settings).

[image]

Hope someone can help explain this. I'm very new to both Meteor and iOS. Sending my [packages](https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/8759cc8c19a5e7be3478) and [platform](https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/71882af42627f70a168a) files as well for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue too. There were one of two things that fixed it:

1) Make sure your project is linked up to your the correct iOS dev team/account & its **not** set to "none":

[image]

2) I had this issue come back again, besides fixing up the above.

So I restarted the computer, logged in and out and deleted the folder over at `.meteor/local/cordova-build` and ran `meteor run ios-device` to rebuild it. This was related to the `mobile-config` file because I changed the name of my app after I ran it the first time. Clearing up the cordova build stuff forced it to rebuild and perhaps this is why it fixe it.

I also deleted the previous app installed on the device (before I renamed the project in `mobile-config.js`. I did this because I suspected it had trouble installing because of the naming changes.